# Livecode/Xcode compatibility

Tags: xcode, livecode

Does anyone know if Livecode 6.6.1 and Xcode 5.1.1 are compatible? If they are not, when can we expect an update from Livecode?  Xcode 5.1.1 has been available since April 11 2014.

Answer (score 3):

With LiveCode 6.6.1, and Xcode 5.1.1, I can both test using the Simulator, iOS 7.1, and I can save a standalone application.

Comment: Works OK here too  :D

Answer (score 0):

there were definite problems with LC 6.6.1 and Xcode 5.1.1

but... more importantly now:
the current build LC 7.0.2 (rc1) is 100% compatible with Xcode 6.1.1 (should be good for the iwatch add-ons too in 6.x.x and AndroidStudio (2.2. - 5.0 target versions)

;-)